# Как эмулировать 30 дней в 1 момент java

Tags: java

Программа выполняет такие действия(действия ниже), то есть получается нужно как бы ускорить время что ли, подскажите пожалуйста как эмулировать эти 30 дней, зариние Спасибо!

- В начале работы программа загружает существующий CSV файл для получения информации об ассортименте и текущем наличии товаров.
- Каждый час в магазин приходит от 1 до 10 покупателей, которые приобретают от 0 до 10 единиц случайных товаров. Цена продажи товаров формируется в соответствии с описанными выше правилами наценки стоимости. Информация о каждой продаже выводится в консоль в процессе работы программы (что продано, цена продажи каждой единицы, какие правила наценки применены).
- По окончании рабочего дня производится дозакупка недостающего товара.
- После эмуляции 30 дней программа сохраняет в текстовый файл отчет, который содержит информацию:
- Количество проданного товара для каждой позиции;

Comment: как ты узнаешь начало и конец рабочего дня, какое сейчас время?

Comment: @пока что этого не делал , но буду использовать Date

Comment: Вопросы вида «Как выполнить задание со следующим списком требований?» слишком широки для Stack Overflow. Можете уточнить в чем именно проблема?

Comment: Минимальный такт какой? 1 час? в 30 днях сколько рабочих часов? Вот и сделайте кол-во итераций равное колву тактов, это тестовое?

Comment: @ default locale я для примера написал список действий которые выполняет программа, что бы было понятно как должна работать эмуляция, те действия делать не нужно, просто надо пример самой эмуляции

Comment: @JVic я новичок в программировании, если бы я знал как это зделать то вопроса бы не задавал=)

Comment: @Сергей тогда непонятно что имеется ввиду под «эмуляцией». Я эмуляцию понимаю как выполнение всех описанных действий, а Вы? Напишите самое простое действие которое Вы хотите сделать и которое не получается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int hourCount = 30 * 8; //8 рабочих часов
for (int i = 0; i < hourCount; i++) {
    if ((i+1) % 8 == 0) { //если последний рабочий час
        делаем закупки
    } else {
        набегают покупатели, короче торговля полным ходом
    }
    записать логи
}  
вывести отчет
```

Comment: @JVic как раз что то похожое я и искал) правда не понял почему 8 рабочих дней, ну да ладно - вообщем понял, спасибо)